# order of coefficients in lm, R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

When running a regression in R, what is the order for the returned coefficients? For example:

```
 coef(lm(y ~ x + z, data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, z=1:5)))
```

Is it guaranteed that the coefficient associated with `x` will always be returned before the coefficient associated with `z`? By order I mean the order in the vector of returned coefficients. The reason this matters for me is I would like to test a linear hypothesis about the coefficients in my model and therefore the order of the coefficients in the variance covariance matrix returned by `vcov` and the actual estimates returned by `coef` matters.

Comment: There is no `z` in your formula.

Comment: oops, typo. just fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Index by name, not by position.  Then you will always get the right answer.

```
coef(lm(y ~ x+z, data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, z=1:5)))['x']
##  x 
## -1 
coef(lm(y ~ x+z, data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, z=1:5)))['z']
##             z 
## -1.855301e-16
```

And both of them, in the desired order:

```
coef(lm(y ~ x+z, data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, z=1:5)))[c('x', 'z')]
##             x             z 
## -1.000000e+00 -1.855301e-16
```

Comment: yeh that's what i'm doing now but when doing interactions some of these have ugly names. for example if i do `lm(y ~ 0 + I(x>2) + x:I(z>2) + z:I(z>2)` they have pretty ugly names but i guess i can still index by them. was hoping there was a better solution

Comment: This is useful advice but does not really answer the question.